# Select an element and its siblings

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

Toggling an element and its siblings can be accomplished as:

```
$(this).toggle();
$(this).prev().toggle();
```

Combining them doesn't work:

```
$(this,$(this).prev()).toggle();
```

How can both be selected at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Incidentally, while this question has already been [answered by drinchev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269566/82548), I thought I'd paste this quick experiment I just did, after reading the question, which also works. Albeit...it surprised me when it did:

```
$('#recipient').click(
    function(){
        var pair = [this, this.previousElementSibling];
        $(pair).toggleClass('red green');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YSUcs/).

Incidentally, a [JS Perf loose comparison of the two selector approaches](http://jsperf.com/previouselementsibling-vs-prev-andself).

---

**Edited** to add an IE-(so far as I know)-friendly update, albeit I'm currently saddling all browsers with it, rather than feature-detecting (also, I finally realised that blue != green):

```
function pESibling(n){
    var nPS = n.previousSibling;
    if (!n || nPS === null){
        return false;
    }
    else if (nPS.nodeType == 1){
        return nPS;
    }
    else {
        return pESibling(nPS);
    }
}

var that = document.getElementById('recipient'),
    pair = [that, pESibling(that)];
$(pair).toggleClass('red green');
console.log(pair);
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YSUcs/4/)

Comment: The joys of the web! No, seriously..! =) To cut a long story short [IE<9 doesn't 'do' `previousElementSibling`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t84). Still, there's the old, and always fashionable, `if` approach. =)

Comment: I was making a stupid mistake when testing your solution.  While, no, `previousElementSibling` won't do the trick, simply using an array will...  `$([$(this),$(this.prev())])` does it!

Comment: There is an easier way $(this).prev().andSelf().toggle();

Answer (score 36):

For jQuery 1.8+, use `.addBack()`:

```
$(this).prev().addBack().toggle();
```

For earlier jQuery versions, use the deprecated `.andSelf()` call (see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8M7Ys/)):

```
$(this).prev().andSelf().toggle();
```

Comment: The *demo* is wrong. The answer is using `prev()` while the demo is using `parent()`, which is not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 11):

for prev siblings and self:

```
$(this).prev().andSelf().toggle();
```

for all siblings and self:

```
$(this).parent().children().toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

Also works:

```
$(this).prev().add($(this)).toggle()
```